# Apple pulp. Can I leave it 24 hours?

Tags: cider

I am making a cider, and trying to break down the labour required to get things moving. I only have evenings to work.

Can I pulp the apples and juice them the following day? I am in the southern UK, and I have to keep the pulp outside but it it frosty cold at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I've done this before with no ill effects. The apples will oxidize and turn brown over night but this doesn't affect the flavor of the juice. As long as you keep the pulp cool, no spontaneous fermentation will occur. I kept mine at a controlled 32 F., but anywhere below 50 F. should be fine for overnight.

Comment: and freezing wouldn't be negative? from what I can tell, it's probably positive, yeah?

Comment: Freezing would help with juice extraction by breaking down cell membranes. The sugars in the pulp will lower the freezing point, so the outside temperature would have to be below freezing for the pulp to freeze.